# Theoretically, about weird but very interesting 3x9 setup? Some knowledge about gearing would be great :)

Tags: crankset, derailleur, vintage

Is it possible to have a 3x9 setup -
Triple 42T ( 42-32-24 )
x 9s ( 11-13-16-20-24-28-32-36-42T )?
The main question is, what kind of 9 speed derailleur is compatible and how long chain need to be for this kind of setup?
Thank you

Comment: What are the tooth counts on your chainrings ?

Comment: The 50T capacity of your rear derailleur; is that the maximum range of chain allowed (from most taught to most slack) OR is 50T the largest cassette cog diameter it can handle?  Listing it as 50T makes me think T = Tooth cog.  Bit if it is chain length capacity it would be 50 links, not teeth.

Comment: Yes that is Max capacity of 9 speed LC derailleur ( 50T ), I found only one model L Twoo A5 Elite 9s LC

Comment: Anecdotally, I ran a similar setup, 3x11, on a 26" touring bike (Surly Troll). A Shimano FC-M8000-3 (40-30-22 chainrings), a CS-M8000 (11-42t), and a RD-M8000-SGS (capacity 47t). As long as you don't cross-chain it works fine, even though you are outside Shimano's specs. A 126-link chain was long enough, and it's perfectly possible to ride up steep hills in the 22-42 without falling over.

Comment: what part of the this setup is weird?

Comment: Not weird, just unusual setup cause front Cranck is Triple 42T ( 42-32-24 )
Rear x9 speed ( 11-13-16-20-24-28-32-36-42T )
But today, finally, after speaking, reading, commenting all information available in the world for almost a month, I decided and order Allblack Shimano Alivio RD M3100 9 speed Shadow SGS  ( Long Cage ) - max. 45T
+ Derailleur Extender  ( max. 52T & 30 speed )
And I hope that was a smart, long tough-out choice..

Answer (score 6):

If you had 42-32-22 in front and 11-42 in back, the derailleur would need 51t of capacity. A bit of casual searching revealed that the highest wrap capacity I could find on a newish derailleur is 47t, which would limit you to a 37t big sprocket in back.

Chain length isn't really a problem--you can find chains long enough for your purposes.

Comment: Yes i have that setup specs to put on a bike.. 3x ( 42-32-22 ) for the front and 9 speed ( 11-42T ) for the back, the derailleur I found, only one that is meeting criteria but there is a catch, it is short for a teeth, it is Chinese derailleur: L Twoo A5 Long Cage Elite max 50T. So will it work?

Comment: Shimano are reasonably conservative with specs; you may find that exceeding the capacity will work well enough for you, especially if you never cross chain.

Comment: I can find chains long enough for a recumbent, basically, you can find bike shops that have 'endless' chains.

Comment: I was checking something and I was wrong, it is not 22, the right number of teeth for the front crank is 42-32-24

Comment: @Chechi'son i wouldnt trust that derailleur to work.  the specifications are unclear.  the manufacturer themselves dont even seem to know the difference between cassette size and tooth capacity

Comment: Today, now I'm thinking to sell this one 3x I got and taking a 2x crankset from Deore, have you any suggestions for a front crankset paired with 9-speed 11-42t cassette?

Comment: One could also just avoid using the 22 / 11 combination, it is redundant with the 32 / 15 ratio available with middle chainring.

Answer (score 5):

22:42 gearing is a ratio of 0.52 or 13.6 gear-inches on 26" wheels.  That will be around 5 km/h or 3 mph in bottom gear at 90 RPM on the crank. You may not be able to balance at such slow speeds and high cadences.

Source https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gear-calc.html

Are you handy with tools?  If you're capable of modifying a rear derailleur and fabricating a longer cage that may be one way to give more capacity.  Downside is the chain gets closer to the ground and will get dirtier, and risks striking rocks more.

As for chain length - if one's not enough you'll need two packs of identical chain and join them.  I find it better to buy three, so I have enough chain for the next replacement without having to source one more identical chain - this helps with tolerances.

Comment: 3x ( 42-32-22 ) for the front and 9 speed ( 11-42T ) for the back, the derailleur I found is L Twoo 9speed A5 Long Cage with max 50T so the question is, will it work..

Comment: In theory, I decided to try this Frankestein configuration, because I have all the parts except the compatabile derilleur. When I go up my favorite hill, it's always at an angle of 115, 120 + degrees and almost every time I die when i reach near the top, and again I want to be able to descend, in peace drive downhill through easy to medium trails ... and maybe more importantly, maintain a relatively high speed in continuity up to 50 km on 26x1.95 tires..

Comment: @Chechi'son  115 degree climb would be an overhang.  The maximum percentage for a paved public  road anywhere in the world is Baldwin Street at about 1:2.86 (19° or 35%)   Off road trails  will be steeper, but you're not riding up a vertical wall.  Can you post a strava segment link ?

Comment: With a 26" or bigger wheel the derailleur case should not be a problem. (I have had a long cage on a 20" recumbent and it did hit the ground on normal roads.)

Comment: lowest gear I used for any amount of time was 22:28 (I might have used the 22:32 for short bits on that same section), and that's already not super stable